# Screen auto rotate only working in live USB, not when installed?

Tags: lenovo, touchscreen, rotate

new to Ubuntu and just installed it on a Lenovo N23 with a touch screen.

The auto-rotation worked fine on the live media USB and had an option to lock and unlock but after the full installation, I'm getting no rotation and nothing in the menu.

Seems I can lock and unlock rotation with a Superkey+O but that just shows if it locked on not, doesn't rotate despite being unlooked.

Could really do with some help.

Hardware: Lenovo N23 WinBook

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

If I run a `systemctl status iio-sensor-proxy`I get the following:

```
 iio-sensor-proxy.service - IIO Sensor Proxy service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iio-sensor-proxy.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-10-17 00:02:26 BST; 11min ago
   Main PID: 682 (iio-sensor-prox)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 4451)
     Memory: 1.2M
        CPU: 473ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/iio-sensor-proxy.service
             └─682 /usr/libexec/iio-sensor-proxy

Oct 17 00:02:25 pigeon-Lenovo-N23 systemd[1]: Starting IIO Sensor Proxy service>
Oct 17 00:02:26 pigeon-Lenovo-N23 systemd[1]: Started IIO Sensor Proxy service.
lines 1-12/12 (END)
```

Running `monitor-sensor` gets me:

```
$ monitor-sensor
    Waiting for iio-sensor-proxy to appear
+++ iio-sensor-proxy appeared
=== Has accelerometer (orientation: normal)
=== No ambient light sensor
=== No proximity sensor
```

And, when I rotate the laptop it prints as expected:

```
Accelerometer orientation changed: right-up
    Accelerometer orientation changed: bottom-up
    Accelerometer orientation changed: left-up
    Accelerometer orientation changed: normal
```

When I put `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` this is the printout:

```
: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event5 
B: PROP=9
B: EV=b
B: KEY=6420 30000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800011000003

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
P: Phys=ideapad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000800100c03 4400000000300000 0 2
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=17c3 Version=0100
N: Name="SYNA7060:00 06CB:17C3"
P: Phys=i2c-SYNA7060:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:05/i2c-1/i2c-SYNA7060:00/0018:06CB:17C3.0001/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
B: MSC=20

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04f2 Product=b5a2 Version=1034
N: Name="Lenovo EasyCamera: EasyCamera"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

I get exactly the same printout if I load into the live media and run `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` But, in the live media it actually rotates the screen as expected.

Hope some of this info in handy, and really sorry for the long post, new to Linux so not sure what was important and what was not.

Comment: You certainly did your homework (by supplying the information). Try to compare the kernel parameters from your live-USB stick and your installed system by executing `sysctl -a` on either. (Rather tedious work). Add the differences of both into your question. Also compare the kernel with `uname -a`